# How to solve this infinite recursion (StackoverflowError) when I use writeValueAsString() method of Jackson ObjectMapper() class?

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I am absolutly new in JSON and how Java handle convert into this format.

So I have the following problem into a Spring MVC application I have this controller method that correctly handle AJAX request toward the **/provinceDiUnaRegione.json** resource:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/provinceDiUnaRegione.json")
@ResponseBody
public String getProvince(String codiceRegione) {

    System.out.println("INTO getProvince()");

    List<Twb1013Provincia> provinceDiUnaRegioneList =  geograficaService.getListaProvinceDiUnaRegione(codiceRegione);

    try {
        String listaProvince = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(provinceDiUnaRegioneList);
        return listaProvince;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return "";

}
```

As you can see this method retrieve a list of **Twb1013Provincia** objects and then use this line to convert the retrieved list into a JSON String (correct me if it is wrong)

```
String listaProvince = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(provinceDiUnaRegioneList);
```

The problem is that when this line is performed I obtain this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Twb1012Regione["tpg1029Provnuoists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafiche.Tpg1029Provnuoist["twb1012Regione"]->it.myCompany.myProject.anagrafic...
```

So doing some analysis it seems to me that the problem is that I am trying to convert a list of **Twb1013Provincia** objects that are something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="anagrafiche.TWB1013_PROVINCIA")
@NamedQuery(name="Twb1013Provincia.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Twb1013Provincia t")
public class Twb1013Provincia implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COD_PRV")
    private String codPrv;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Twb1012Regione
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="COD_REG")
    private Twb1012Regione twb1012Regione;

    .................................................
    .................................................
    OTHER FIELDS
    .................................................
    .................................................
}
```

The problems seems that, as you can see, this class contain a **Twb1012Regione twb1012Regione;** field and that this **Twb1012Regione** class contain in turn a reference to the original **Twb1013Provincia** (the object to convert), something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="anagrafiche.TWB1012_REGIONE")
@NamedQuery(name="Twb1012Regione.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Twb1012Regione t")
public class Twb1012Regione implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COD_REG")
    private String codReg;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Twb1013Provincia
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="twb1012Regione")
    private List<Twb1013Provincia> twb1013Provincias;

    .................................................
    .................................................
    OTHER FIELDS
    .................................................
    .................................................
}
```

So the problems seems to be that when I try to convert a **Twb1013Provincia** object it find inside it a **Twb1012Regione** field that itself contain an **Twb1013Provincia**...so enter in an infinite loop and the conversion is impossible.

So how can I solve this issue? Exist a way to exclude the **Twb1012Regione** field from the **Twb1013Provincia** object conversion?

Or better can I specify the list of the **Twb1013Provincia** class fields that have to be converted in JSON format? (I need to convert only 2 fields of this class)

Tnx

Comment: Have you tried adding JSONignore annotation to avoid serializing dependent object to JSON?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can exclude a field from serializing using [@JsonIgnore](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation.

Try:

```
@JsonIgnore
private Twb1012Regione twb1012Regione;
```

Comment: Also you can use the transient keyword from plain Java, and declare that attribute as private transient, to avoid its serialization into the Json string.

Comment: There are other options besides JsonIgnore:
1. Use JsonManagedReference, JsonBackReference
2. Use JsonIdentityInfo
3. Use JsonIgnore
4. Use JsonView
see [Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)